# custom char filter of elastic search is not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the custom analyzer shown below

```
{
  "settings": {
  "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
        "query_logging_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "char_filter": [
          {
            "type": "mapping",
            "mappings": [
              "'=>\\u0020",
              "{=>\\u0020",
              "}=>\\u0020",
              ",=>\\u0020",
              ":=>\\u0020",
              "[=>\\u0020",
              "]=>\\u0020"
            ]
         }
       ]
     }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

basically I want an analyzer that takes in a json string and emits out the keys of that json. For that purpose, I need to tidy up the json by removing json entities such as `[ ] { } , : "`

This somehow is not working. The char_filter isnt taking effect at all

I had a similar char_filter using pattern_replace which didn't work too

```
 "char_filter": [
        {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "\"|\\,|\\:|\\'|\\{|\\}",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is 'not working'?
Because your custom Analyzer seems to work just fine?

```
GET _analyze?filter_path=tokens.token
{
  "tokenizer": "whitespace",
  "text": [
    """{ "names": [ "Foo", "Bar" ] }"""
  ],
  "char_filter": [
    {
      "type": "mapping",
      "mappings": [
        "'=>\\u0020",
        "{=>\\u0020",
        "}=>\\u0020",
        ",=>\\u0020",
        ":=>\\u0020",
        "[=>\\u0020",
        "]=>\\u0020"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Returns:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": """"names""""
    },
    {
      "token": """"Foo""""
    },
    {
      "token": """"Bar""""
    }
  ]
}
```